# Whitespace below div only on Android

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

This is really weird. Whenever I go to view my website on my Android Google Pixel, there is whitespace. However, on Chrome with the size of my phone, there is none. Sorry for no pic, as imgur is for some reason rejecting my snapshot (1.1mb).

```
html,body{ 
    height: 100% !important; 
}

#nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw !important;
}
#headerContainer{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('/img/info.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
#headerContent{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 22.5px;
}
#headerContent hr{
    width: 75%;
    height: 2px;
    border: none;
    background-color: white;

}
.blog{
    display: inline !important;
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
#about{
    background-image: url('/img/about.jpg');
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: left;
    height: 60vh;
}
#about h2{
    text-align: center;
}
#about p,#about h2{
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(145,134,115,0.5);
    margin: 0;
    width: 25%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px){
    #about{
        display: block;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
    #about p{
        width: 25%;
        height: 93.9%;
        padding-top: 2.5%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:500px) and (max-width: 600px){
    #about{
        height: 100%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    html,body{ 
        height: 100% !important; 
    }
    #headerContent p{
        font-size: 32px !important;
    }
    #headerContainer{
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    #about{
        display: block;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100% !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    #about p,#about h2{
        display: block;
        top: 0%;
        left:0%;
        width:45%;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
    #nav{
        position: relative !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

It is really weird. I have looked this issue up and no one has had this one specifically.

[image]

Comment: can you please provide the running code sample or url of your website?

Comment: Sorry, it isn't live. Only on my computer.

Comment: FYI, I have the CSS code listed above.

Comment: yaa but it's not that clear for me. If you can create some example on jsfiddle or codepen then that would be great.

Comment: ok sounds good.

Comment: The jsfiddle is not showing what I am seeing on my phone. I will not provide a link, as it will not help.

Comment: Ok no problem ... then i can not help you.. sorry buddy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL! I had an ad at the bottom and it didn't load (403)!